# Bug al hacer OnClick en un CardView de un RecycleView. Al manipular la vista, esta se repite reiteradamente

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview, onclick, android-recyclerview, cardview

Estoy con este problema y me tiene tomado de los pelos. Ya consulte por todos lados y no veo como salir de esto. Lo que sucede sencillamente es que en un CardView tengo una serie de tarjetas (cards) y al pulsar sobre ellas, la tarjeta muestra partes ocultas de la misma. Pero si me desplazo para abajo y espero que carge el resto de las tarjetas, veo que la vista se repite reiteradamente con los botones sin ocultar. O sea, si pulso la tarje numero 2 por ejemplo, en la tarjeta numero 15 aparece como si hubiera pulsado la tarjeta y asi cada x cantidades de tarjetas. Es como si reciclara la misma vista de la tarjeta ¿a alguno ya le pasó esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si a mi me esta faltando agregar algo o tengo un error conceptual. Estoy necesitando realmente usar un recycleview y no un listview, por un tema de memoria, la lista es extensa. Me da la impresión que todo el lio esta en la funcion loadMore, si juego con los notificadores del reciclador (notifyItemInserted por ejemplo), la repeticion se da en distintos lugares de la lista. Por favor, si pueden dar una mano para evitar esto estaria super agradecido.

CardAdapter.java

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private void populateItemRows(CardViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final String tittle = cardList.get(position).getTittle();

    mHolder = (CardViewHolder) holder;

    mHolder.txtTittle.setText(tittle);

 
    mHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(filteredCardList.get(position).isExpanded()) {

                collapse(position);
                filteredCardList.get(position).setExpanded(false);
                setExpandedItem(-1); // -1 significa que todas las tarjetas estan cerradas

            } else {

                if(getExpandedItem()!=position&&getExpandedItem()!=-1) {

                    collapse(getExpandedItem()); // cierro la tarjeta anterior
                    filteredCardList.get(getExpandedItem()).setExpanded(false);

                }

                collapse(position); // abro la tarjeta pulsada

                filteredCardList.get(position).setExpanded(true); 
                setExpandedItem(position); // grabo la tarjeta pulsada

            }

        }
    });

}


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void collapse(int position) {

    View mViewCard = Objects.requireNonNull(mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)).itemView;

    int expanded = 0;
    if(!cardList.get(position).isExpanded())
        expanded = 1;

    if(expanded==1) {

        mViewCard.findViewById(R.id.screenBlank).setBackgroundColor(r.getColor(R.color.black_opacity_80));

        mViewCard.findViewById(R.id.subtittleText).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mViewCard.findViewById(R.id.card_btn_info).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {

        mViewCard.findViewById(R.id.screenBlank).setBackgroundColor(r.getColor(R.color.black_opacity_60));

        mViewCard.findViewById(R.id.subtittleText).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mViewCard.findViewById(R.id.card_btn_info).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

}

public void loadInit(int initSize) {

    Card card;
    int position = 0;

    cardList.clear();

    while(position <= initSize && position < filteredCardList.size()) {

        card = filteredCardList.get(position);
        cardList.add(card);
        position++;

    }

    notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);

    this.currentSize = cardList.size();
    isLoading = false;

}

public void loadMore() {
    int load_delay = 500;

    cardList.add(null);

    mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);
        }
    });


    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            cardList.remove(getItemCount() - 1);

            notifyItemRemoved(getItemCount());

            int position = currentSize;
            Card card;

            currentSize += incremental;

            while (position <= currentSize && position < filteredCardList.size()) {

                card = filteredCardList.get(position);
                cardList.add(card);

                position++;

            }

            notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);

            currentSize = cardList.size();
            isLoading = false;

        }
    }, load_delay);

}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(cardFilter == null)
        cardFilter = new cardFilter(this, fullCardList);
    return cardFilter;
}
```

card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/idCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/transparentLow">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/screenBlank"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black_opacity_60" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_plain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tittleText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary_100"
            android:textSize="@dimen/card_textSize_primary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/subtittleText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtittleText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/card_info_free"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary_100"
            android:textSize="@dimen/card_textSize_secondary"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tittleText"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/card_btn_info" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/card_btn_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="25dp"
            android:paddingVertical="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/item_info_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/card_info"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary_100"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subtittleText" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

onScroll para llamar a loadMore

```
    private void initScrollListener() {

    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

            if(!mAdapter.cardListContainer.isFinish()) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

                if(mAdapter.currentSize < mAdapter.filteredCardList.size() - 1) {

                    if (!mAdapter.isLoading && linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1) {

                        mAdapter.isLoading = true;
                        mAdapter.loadMore();

                    }

                }

            }
        }
    });

}
```

No se que otra cosa necesitan revisar. Algo me huele que aplico mal un concepto de Recycleview ¿hay alguna manera de evitar este bug?

PD: Como ven. utiliza varias listas ya que tambien tengo la opción para buscar y filtrar. Una es filteredlist (la lista filtrada), otra cardList (la lista que se muestra en pantalla) y fullCardList (la lista con todos los elementos que existen, cual aplico el filtro). No pongo todas sus funciones porque es un código extenso, ya me entenderán.

DEBUG - Se agregan unos Log.d en el código:

```
Log.d("DEBUG","currentSize:"+currentSize);
            Log.d("DEBUG","filteredCardList.size:"+filteredCardList.size());
            while (position <= currentSize && position < filteredCardList.size()) {
                Log.d("DEBUG","add card position:"+position);

                card = filteredCardList.get(position);
                cardList.add(card);

                position++;

            }

            notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);

            currentSize = cardList.size();
            Log.d("DEBUG","cardList.size:"+cardList.size());
```

Resultado:

```
// PULSO SOBRE TARJETA 2
D/DATA: getExpanded anterior:-1
D/OPERATION: ABRIENDO
D/DATA: getExpanded nuevo:1
// ME DESPLAZO AL FINAL DE LA LISTA
D/DEBUG: currentSize:10
filteredCardList.size:53
add card position:5
add card position:6
add card position:7
add card position:8
// LA POSICION 8 FIGURA LA TARJETA ABIERTA
add card position:9
add card position:10
D/DEBUG: cardList.size:11
// ME DESPLAZO AL FINAL DE LA LISTA UNA VEZ MAS
D/DEBUG: currentSize:16
D/DEBUG: filteredCardList.size:53
add card position:11
add card position:12
add card position:13
add card position:14
add card position:15
// LA POSICION 15 FIGURA LA TARJETA ABIERTA
add card position:16
cardList.size:17
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=503KB, data=373KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=433KB, data=291KB
```

También puede ser que sea esto:
Objects.requireNonNull(mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)).itemView

Ya que esta sentencia podría estar seleccionado mas de una view para un viewHolder ¿Se puede sustituir por otra similar?

Comment: Haz debug de algún modo en este bucle `while (position <= currentSize && position < filteredCardList.size()) {` y revisa lo que ocurre en él, puede que el problema esté ahí. No es fácil saberlo sin un contexto completo. Sugiero que depures tu código, imprimiendo valores en el Log por ejemplo y revisando.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Agrege unos log.d en el trayecto. Ahora te copio el resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolvi con holder.setIsRecyclable(false) en onBindViewHolder. Eso desactiva la opción de reciclar para todos las vistas.